# How to execute scriptler script in jenkins remotely / via REST API?

Tags: jenkins, curl, jenkins-scriptler

In Jenkins, I would like to execute my scriptler script via REST API from bash and curl. According to [documentation](https://plugins.jenkins.io/scriptler/) it should work, but there isn't any working example.

I have created simple script `testScr`, which is just one liner: `println "OK"`. I'm trying to execute it with `curl`:

`curl -d '{}' --user <userid>:<Token> http://<jenkins_server>/scriptler/run/testScr  > result.html`

Resulting html says: **"Oops! A problem occurred while processing the request."**

How to do it correctly? Is even it working for somebody?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that works for me.
Have you made sure that the user have the right permission and the token is corrct?

In my case I'm using [Role-based Authorization Strategy](https://plugins.jenkins.io/role-strategy/)

And you can execute it if you're admin

[image]

if you want another user different that admin execute it you can also grant permissions

[image]